# ExpressJs configuring html and css pages

Tags: javascript, html, css, express, asset-pipeline

I am a newbie in ExpressJs. I have tried using html and css while building the app. But there is always asset-pipelining problem. Sometime css could not be loaded and sometime it does not get refreshed even if I restart the server. I have used static serve method. Still could not figure out the problem. Please help me out of this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is the solution

```
 install npm serve-static
```

this should solve the problem